# how parse all data-count-on-hand variable

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

i want to find the 'data-count-on-hand=' variable in this part of code, but the response is none.

```html
size_container = soup.find("ul",{"class":"styled-radio"})
stock2 = size_container.find_all("li")
stock = stock2["li"].split("data-count-on-hand")[1]
```

that's what i tried
that's the html i need to soup :

```html
<ul class="styled-radio">
<li>
<input type="radio" name="variant_id" id="variant_id_112240" value="112240" class="js-change-quantity" data-options-threshold="5">
<label for="variant_id_112240">XS</label>
</li>
<li>
<input type="radio" name="variant_id" id="variant_id_112238" value="112238" class="js-change-quantity" data-count-on-hand="96" data-options-threshold="5">
<label for="variant_id_112238">S</label>
</li>
<li>
<input type="radio" name="variant_id" id="variant_id_112237" value="112237" class="js-change-quantity" data-count-on-hand="8" data-options-threshold="5">
<label for="variant_id_112237">M</label>
</li>
<li>
<input type="radio" name="variant_id" id="variant_id_112241" value="112241" class="js-change-quantity" data-count-on-hand="18" data-options-threshold="5">
<label for="variant_id_112241">XXL</label>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `input` tags having `data-count-on-hand` attribute. Each tag can be treated like a dictionary of attribute-value pairs.

```
for input in soup.find_all('input',attrs={'data-count-on-hand':True}):
    print(input['data-count-on-hand'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out some different selectors as you may be able to just use an attribute selector, for example, without class `[data-count-on-hand]`. The with class is `.js-change-quantity[data-count-on-hand]`

```
stocks = [item['data-count-on-hand'] for item in soup.select('.js-change-quantity[data-count-on-hand]')]
```

As in answer already given, if you want to use type selector of `input` for the `input` tag, change selector to:

```
soup.select('input[data-count-on-hand]')
```